# Download files modified in last 30 minutes from a URL

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to download only files modified in the last 30 minutes from a URL. Can you please guide me how to proceed with this. Please let me know if I should use shell scripting or python scripting for this.

Comment: How does the URL tell you when a file was modified?

Answer (score 2):

If the server supports if-modified-since, you could send the request with If-Modified-Since: (T-30 minutes) and ignore the 304 responses.

Comment: Hello,I am new to this server stuff. Can you please let me know how to find this?

Comment: This how it looks in the index.html page HREF="/REPORTS/CURRENT/STTM/DAY31.ZIP">DAY31.ZIP</A><br>  Wednesday, October 17, 2012  1:44 PM         1956 <A                                                I need to schedule my job every half hour and find if something has changed since 30 minutes and then download the files.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time the names of the files you need to check?

Comment: They may post new files as well. DAY[digits].ZIP and INT*.CSV.  I was trying to use python urllib to read and parse index.html. Not sure if it is the right way to do it. I need to look for anything with *.ZIP and *.CSV. Please advise.

Comment: Give this a try: `wget -r --header="If-Modified-Since:(one half hour ago)" (your url)`

Comment: I believe this works if I have the files on my local directory right? I am not supposed to save the files on my local directory due to space issues.                                                                      URL: http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/STTM/

Comment: That will pull down files from the server that have been modified within the last half hour.

Comment: How do I find this If-Modified-Since header on the URL?

Comment: It's a regular date, the full command would be: `wget -r -l 1 --header="If-Modified-Since:Wed, 17 Oct 2012 16:35:42 GMT" http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/STTM/`  notice that I added the `-l 1` flag, that's important or otherwise it would go through the entire server rather than that one directory.

Comment: If I need to get only *.CSV and *.ZIP, do I have to specify anything in the wget command. I am new to these.

Comment: In that case it would be `wget --recursive --level=1 --accept=CSV,ZIP --header="If-Modified-Since:Wed, 17 Oct 2012 16:35:42 GMT" http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/STTM/`

Comment: I am US EST zone and the files are in GMT time (australia time) I used this: wget --recursive --level=1 --accept=CSV -nd -nc --header="If-Modified-Since:`date`" http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/STTM/. Looks like it downloads everything. Should I be using any date conversions here?

Comment: I mean the files are in Australia time zone in the URL

Comment: The server should understand the EDT timezone so you can use your local time as long as you specify "EDT"

Comment: this works -                                                                wget --recursive --level=1 --accept=CSV -nd -nc --header="If-Modified-Since:$(date +\%a", "\%d" "%b" "\%Y" "\%H":"\%M":"\%S" GMT")" http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/STTM/. thank you for your answers. I was trying to code using python. One command does everything for me. Appreciate your help

Comment: No problem, I like to brush up on wget every once in a while, it's very powerful

Comment: One question on date: $(date +\%a", "\%d" "%b" "\%Y" "\%H":"\%M":"\%S" GMT" Does this give GMT date when I run the command on linux even if my server is on EDT

Comment: you answered earlier. Sorry missed it.

Comment: Is there a way to get md5sum of a file using wget?

Comment: I've never tried but you may be able to pipe it to md5sum like in this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19049/obtaining-md5-during-wget